# How to use Spring Boot with existing Tomcat without war deployment

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a maven project that uses spring data jpa and hibernate (Services, Entities, Repositories, ...). Everything is compiled to a jar file with AspectJ.

Now I wanted to add a REST API in order to receive POST/GET messages. So I added spring boot and spring web to add RequestMappings ans Controller to my project.

The problem is, that I can **not** modify the `main(String[] args)` method of the project so I can not add the Spring boot context in order to use the build in Tomcat.

Because of that I am wondering if I could use a tomcat that is installed on the machine where my jar file will be executed.

The only way that I found on StackOverflow is to compile a war and deploy it on the Tomcat. But I am very limited in my project architecture. So the fact that I have a jar file that must be located in a specific folder and also my restriction not to modify the `main(String[] args)` method is a little bit annoying. So can I somehow tell spring to use the existing tomcat and listen to the incoming connections? Or is there an other way to get a working REST API to this kind of project structure?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use existing Tomcat instance you *should* deploy a war file to it. The instance is running it's own JVM and to hook into it you should provide `ServletInitializer`.

See detailed description how to [Deploying Spring Boot Applications. What about the Java EE Application Server?](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications#what-about-the-java-ee-application-server).

> But, I imagine you wondering, “how do I deploy it to an existing
>   Tomcat installation, or to the classic Java EE application servers
>   (some of which cost a lot of money!) like WebSphere, WebLogic, or
>   JBoss?” Easy! It’s still just Spring, after all, so very little else
>   is required. You’ll need to make three intuitive changes: move from a
>   jar build to a war build in Maven: comment out the declaration of the
>   spring-boot-maven-plugin plugin in your `pom.xml` file, then change the
>   Maven packaging type to war. Finally, add a web entry point into your
>   application.

---

You should read this document further where you can make changes to `pom.xml` to exclude not used dependencies.

> You may experience issues if you have classes that conflict with those
>   that ship as parter of a larger application server. In this case, use
>   your build tool’s facilities for excluding or making optional the
>   relevant APIs.

---

Answer (score 0):

Migrate from JAR to WAR:

- Change the packaging on pom.xml:

`<packaging>war</packaging>`

- Make sure you have these *dependencies* exactly like that:

`<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>`

- Create ServletInitializer exactly on the same path that SpringApplication.run is invoked.

  ```
  package com.example;

  import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
  import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

  public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

      @Override
      protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
          return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
      }
  }
  ```
- *P.S.:* I also recommend putting on pom.xml, inside "" tag, the following parameter with the context of your project:

`<finalName>myProject</finalName>`

Source: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging

Comment: tomcat should be excluded